# Node.Js Using NPM mssql connectionPool to trigger multiple queries async

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

The connectionPool from mssql is connected to the MSSQL late before my multiple queries are fired. How to make sure that the connectionPool is connected before? 
Here is the snippet:

```
return connectionPool.request().query(completeSql)
.then(result => {
//console.dir(" ********** getTravellerBookingNameAndMemberIdByActiveAlertAndAlertLocation RESULTS ", result.recordsets[0]);
    return result.recordsets[0];
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This block is inside a method which is fired multiple times with different queries.

Comment: I solved this issue by using tedious-promises and tedious-connection-pool. Check https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool and https://github.com/chilltemp/tedious-promises.